# Bootstrap responsive vertical timeline with icons and image placeholders

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help to achieve a vertical timeline with icons and placeholders as per the image.

[image]

I am using the code snippet [here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/timeline-responsive), but I cannot overcome the timeline design with css3.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Paulie-D the tutorial does not guide me to create the quarter circles with css and implement them in the list.

Comment: So that's the only issue...the quarter borders? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Do you want Paulie to code it all for you too?

Comment: Yes as mentioned in my question the trouble that I am finding is to create the vertical timeline design with css as the vert which is made from lists is stacking solid and removes the quarter circle borders.

Comment: So perhaps you should [edit] the question to explain what it is **precisely** that you are after and what you have tried to do to solve it, At the moment this is just a vague code request question. Also a search on SO would probably find that this has come up before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be the quarter-circle borders you want.

This can be acheived by setting a simple rotate transformation on the element and then rotating any content back the other way.

Then border colors can be set individually.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: grey transparent;
  margin: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  font-size: 36px
}
div i {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Paulie, I like your approach and will be trying it later on. I was trying to style the quarter halves on the unordered lists that create the vertical timeline with before and after classes which got messier the more I tried and tried. Keeping to the code snippet, I would implement your code to the timeline-badge

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .glyphicon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```